# How do I call a created function for multiple elements at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a brief function just to illustrate my point.

Suppose I have created an `myFunction()` function that does the following service:

```
function myFunction(element,property,color){
    $(element).css(property,color);
};
```

Then for each element that I want to apply this function I will use:

```
myFunction('div','background-color','green');
myFunction('span','border-color','blue');
myFunction('i','color','red');
```

A demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/h4yY3/

But I wish i could call the function only once for all these handlers. For example, I could do something like:

```
function myFunction({element,property,color}){
...
}

myFunction({'div','background-color','green'},{'span','border-color','blue'},{'i','color','red'});
```

Could someone please teach me the correct way to do this? I tried a search but do not know if I'm using the correct terms to refer to this as 'handler'.

Please, suggest.
Thank you.

Comment: Why would you create a function at all, if you just use jQuery's css() you can add as many styles as you'd like ?

Comment: in this specific example, you're actually becoming less efficient than just using jQuery's `.css()`. In general, what you're describing is not really done... you can pass arrays instead of strings and then loops through them if you would really like to do that.

Comment: @adeneo I created this example only to illustrate the situation I have. Im sure in its actual application I need this function because I work with some variables.

Comment: `css()` accepts variables just fine! Anyway you twist and turn this you're going to come out worse than just using jQuery directly.

Comment: @adeneo My point in raising this topic was not to discuss the efficiency of this code, I'm not even working with css, it was only to illustrate my need. I'm sorry if I was not clear enough, but I'm waiting for suggestions of how to call a function with multiple hanlders and not to improve the performance of this action.

Comment: That should be pretty straight forward, this version would work with both types of arguments -> **http://jsfiddle.net/h4yY3/2/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following (given your description):

```
// @args { elm: ELM, prop: PROPERTY, val: VALUE },...
function applyCSS() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments),
      len = args.length;
  while (len--) {
    var cfg = args[len];
    $(cfg.elm).css(cfg.prop, cfg.val);
  }
}

applyCSS(
  { elm: '.block', prop: 'background-color', val: '#ccc'},
  { elm: '.para', prop: 'color', val: 'blue' },
  { elm: '.thing', prop: 'font-size', val: '14pt' }
);
```

See this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yoqip/1/) for an example.

**Update**: Inspired by @ActiveHigh's version, I think this might be a better organization of the arguments for the function to allow modifying multiple properties on multiple elements in one call (same JSBin example above):

```
// Alternative version to allow multiple properties per element to be set.
// @args { 'elm': { prop: val, ... }, ... }
function applyCSS2(obj) {
  var elms = Object.keys(obj),
      len = elms.length;

  $.map(elms, function(elm) {
    $(elm).css(obj[elm]);
  });
}
```

Calling it would look like the following:

```
applyCSS2({
  '.block': { 'background-color': '#ccc', 'color': '#fff' },
  '.para': { 'color': 'blue', 'font-family': 'Verdana, sans-serif' },
  '.thing': { 'font-size': '14pt', 'letter-spacing': '1em' }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the best way to do this without the need to create a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this helps. I modified the array a little bit for efficiency -

```
var dummy = [["div", {'color':'red', 'background': 'red'}], 
             ["span", {'color':'red', 'background': 'red'}],
             ["li", {'color':'red', 'background': 'red'}]]
var cssFunction = function (items) {
        $.map(items, function(item){
             $(item[0]).css(item[1]);
        });
    };
cssFunction(dummy);
```

Comment: I like this version better than mine, much cleaner with map, and just taking the CSS prop arguments and applying them as is, which allows multiple properties to be set on an element in one call.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can apply css as you want with jquery directly:

```
$(selector).css({color:"red",background:"black"})
```

Here an example of what you want

http://jsbin.com/molifece/2/edit

Comment: Thanks, but does not answer my question. I'm not looking for a way to optimize my code. I am looking for a way to call multiple handlers in the same function.